# hello world sinatra app error

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm having trouble learning how to use Sinatra.  I finally got phusion-passenger installed and working with my apache2 on Ubuntu.  I have the following directories and files

```
/var/www/html
/var/www/html/public
/var/www/html/tmp
/var/www/html/config.ru   # this is a file
```

The contents of `/var/www/html/config.ru` is copied from https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_tutorial_example_writing_and_deploying_a_hello_world_rack_application.

When I start up this application, I get hello world, which is great.

So next, I want to build a Sinatra app.  I went ahead and created the file

```
/var/www/html/myapp.rb
```

With the contents described by http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html .  I also did a `gem install sinatra`.  I restarted apache.  Then I went to `http://localhost/` but I still see `hello world` of my `config.ru`.  So then I overwrote the contents of `config.ru` with `myapp.rb`.  I restarted apache.  But now I get an error message

```
missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:133:in `to_app'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I build a hello world Sinatra app?

Comment: I'd recommend learning and testing Sinatra in its stand-alone mode first. Once you're comfortable with it that way, then wire it into Passenger. Trying to use Passenger initially only clouds what you need to understand and makes it more difficult to figure out which does what in the stack. By itself, Sinatra is extremely easy to use, and doesn't take anything else to handle HTTP requests. It's quite a capable little web-server DSL, especially when paired with Haml and Thin. Sinatra's home page shows how to create a "hello world" app, and it really only takes three lines of code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `config.ru` should require and run your app, like:

```
require './myapp.rb' 
run Sinatra::Application
```

And in turn, myapp should require sinatra:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end
```

Read on about using a config.ru: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Using%20a%20Classic%20Style%20Application%20with%20a%20config.ru

Comment: thank you...getting through this initial learning of ruby is so painful

Comment: Don't confuse Ruby with Sinatra's DSL, and Apache and Passenger. All have their learning curve and trying to do them all at once will be very confusing. Learn Ruby, then toss in Sinatra, then add the others. It'll make more sense.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man.  I'm now starting to understand that I am indeed confusing all these technologies together...mostly i'm under the impression each are dependent on each other in order to work.  And i'm slowly learnig that's not the case.